# How to install tomcat-native without need to install development utils

Tags: installation, tomcat, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am using tomcat on a RHEL machine.
When starting tomcat, i get the following warning:

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was no 64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib

Then i tried to install the native library.
The tomcat documentation says i need to compile it by myself.

But this would require to install ant, a jdk, a c-compiler and some *-devel packages.
I don't want to install those bloaty stuff on my production server just to be able to install a certain library.

Am I the only one having this problem?
Is there someone who uses tomcat-native on a production server without having compilers installed there?

Thanks, Andre

Comment: You sure that wording of the warning is correct?  The warning basically seems to be saying, your not running a 64-bit process, if you don't care about that just ignore it.